# How to navigate between view models via BottomNavigationView in Xamarin MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Let's say we have MvvmCross 6.0.1 native app with one Android Activity containing `BottomNavigationView` implemented as in [this blog post by James Montemagno](https://blog.xamarin.com/exploring-androids-bottom-navigation-view/) but without navigating and replacing fragments.

What I would like to do is to bind `BottomNavigationView` items to MvxCommands (or MvxAsyncCommands) in ViewModel in order to navigate between several ViewModels.

What kind of *architecture* should I apply to achieve this? **Is my approach correct or am I doing something against MVVM pattern and MvvmCross possibilities?**

Full working example with several additions can be found [here on github](https://github.com/orestesgaolin/bottomnavview-xamarin-example).

[image: animated gif showing current progress]

At the moment I have (scaffolded with [MvxScaffolding](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/MvxScaffolding)).

- `MainContainerActivity` and corresponding `MainContainerViewModel` - here I would like to store commands to navigate between view models
- `MainFragment` and corresponding `MainViewModel` - this is the first fragment/view model
- `SettingsFragment` and corresponding `SettingsViewModel` - I would like to navigate to it from `MainViewModel` and vice versa
- `FavoritesFragment` and corresponding `FavoritesViewModel`

The main activity is as follows:

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using PushNotifTest.Core.ViewModels.Main;
using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Push;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace PushNotifTest.Droid.Views.Main
{
    [Activity(
        Theme = "@style/AppTheme",
        WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize | SoftInput.StateHidden)]
    public class MainContainerActivity : BaseActivity<MainContainerViewModel>
    {
        protected override int ActivityLayoutId => Resource.Layout.activity_main_container;

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;

        public ICommand GoToSettingsCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand GoToFavoritesCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand GoToHomeCommand { get; set; }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            AddBottomNavigation();
        }

        private void AddBottomNavigation()
        {
            bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
            if (bottomNavigation != null)
            {
                bottomNavigation.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected;
                // trying to bind command to view model property
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainContainerActivity, MainContainerViewModel>();
                set.Bind(this).For(v => v.GoToSettingsCommand).To(vm => vm.NavigateToSettingsCommand);
                set.Bind(this).For(v => v.GoToHomeCommand).To(vm => vm.NavigateToHomeCommand);
                set.Bind(this).For(v => v.GoToFavoritesCommand).To(vm => vm.NavigateToFavoritesCommand);
                set.Apply();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bottom navigation menu is null");
            }
        }

        private void BottomNavigation_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Bottom navigation menu is selected: {e.Item.ItemId}");

                if (e.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_settings)
                    if (GoToSettingsCommand != null && GoToSettingsCommand.CanExecute(null))
                        GoToSettingsCommand.Execute(null);
                if (e.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_list)
                    if (GoToFavoritesCommand != null && GoToFavoritesCommand.CanExecute(null))
                        GoToFavoritesCommand.Execute(null);
                if (e.Item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_home)
                    if (GoToHomeCommand != null && GoToHomeCommand.CanExecute(null))
                        GoToHomeCommand.Execute(null);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {exception.Message}");
                Crashes.TrackError(exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The bottom navigation elements are:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_home"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_history"
      android:title="@string/tab1_title"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

  <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_list"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
      android:title="@string/tab2_title"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

  <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
      android:title="@string/tab3_title"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

And the commands in view model are just:

```cs
public IMvxAsyncCommand NavigateToSettingsCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await _navigationService.Navigate<SettingsViewModel>());
public IMvxAsyncCommand NavigateToFavoritesCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await _navigationService.Navigate<FavoritesViewModel>());
public IMvxAsyncCommand NavigateToHomeCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await _navigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>());
```

Comment: Hello, I am not sure what your problem is.

Comment: I'd like to get some comment on my approach - it seems that there's too much code to perform just simple navigation. Seems that it's against some basic rules and it's hard to maintain. If you can share some better approach I would be more than grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Fluent Binding, you could create a targeted binding for the BottomNavigationView and handle the navigation in your MainViewModel. Use Swiss binding in your XML.

**TargetBinding Class:**

```
public class MvxBottomNavigationItemChangedBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
    {
        readonly BottomNavigationView _bottomNav;
        IMvxCommand _command;

        public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.TwoWay;
        public override Type TargetType => typeof(MvxCommand);

        public MvxBottomNavigationItemChangedBinding(BottomNavigationView bottomNav) : base(bottomNav)
        {
            _bottomNav = bottomNav;
            _bottomNav.NavigationItemSelected += OnNavigationItemSelected;
        }

        public override void SetValue(object value)
        {
            _command = (IMvxCommand)value;
        }

        protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
        {

        }

        void OnNavigationItemSelected(object sender, BottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_command != null)
                _command.Execute(e.Item.TitleCondensedFormatted.ToString());
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
                _bottomNav.NavigationItemSelected -= OnNavigationItemSelected;

            base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        }
    }
```

**Setup.cs :**

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
        {
            MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories(registry);
            base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
            registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<BottomNavigationView>("BottomNavigationSelectedBindingKey",
                                                                        view => new MvxBottomNavigationItemChangedBinding(view));

        }
```

**BottomNavigationView XML :**

Note the target binding key that we added in Setup.cs is used when binding.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:elevation="10dp"
            local:MvxBind="BottomNavigationSelectedBindingKey BottomNavigationItemSelectedCommand"/>
```

**MainViewModel :**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
public IMvxCommand<string> BottomNavigationItemSelectedCommand { get; private set; }

List<TabViewModel> _tabs;
public List<TabViewModel> Tabs
{
    get => _tabs;
    set => SetProperty(ref _tabs, value);
}

public MainViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
{
    //these are for android - start
    BottomNavigationItemSelectedCommand = new MvxCommand<string>(BottomNavigationItemSelected);

    var tabs = new List<TabViewModel>
    {
        Mvx.IoCProvider.IoCConstruct<FirstViewModel>(),
        Mvx.IoCProvider.IoCConstruct<SecondViewModel>(),
        Mvx.IoCProvider.IoCConstruct<ThirdViewModel>()
    };

    Tabs = tabs;
    //end
}

// Android-only, not used on iOS
private void BottomNavigationItemSelected(string tabId)
{
    if (tabId == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var item in Tabs)
    {
        if (tabId == item.TabId)
        {
            _navigationService.Navigate(item);
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**TabViewModel :**

```
public class TabViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public string TabName { get; protected set; }
        public string TabId { get; protected set; }

        public TabViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
           
        }
    }
```

**BottomNavigation Elements:**

Add "**android:titleCondensed**", which will be used as the Id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_home"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_history"
      android:title="@string/tab1_title"
      android:titleCondensed ="tab_first"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

  <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_list"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
      android:title="@string/tab2_title"
      android:titleCondensed ="tab_second"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

  <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
      android:title="@string/tab3_title"
      android:titleCondensed ="tab_third"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

**ViewModel Examples:**

```
public class FirstViewModel : TabViewModel
{
    public FirstViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            TabId = "tab_first";
        }
}

public class SecondViewModel : TabViewModel
{
    public SecondViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            TabId = "tab_second";
        }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else who comes into this later on ! :)